# Audio player doesn't read some songs

Tags: audio, hyundai

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, so if it isn't feel free to move or delete or whatever.

I just burned an MP3 cd with about 80 songs on it, and it plays fine on my computer. When I put it in my car, though, only some of the songs play. The songs all started out in different formats (AAC, Protected AAC, Purchased AAC) but I converted them all (in iTunes) to MP3s ('MPEG audio file').

I burned them all to a cd in iTunes (MP3 CD, 8x speed, just to be safe), and when I put it in my car, only some of the songs play.

It's a 2006 Hyundai Sonata, if that matters.

Any ideas why only some of the songs, but not all, would be playing?

Comment: I can't say this is the wrong place to post this question, but you might get better results on Super User. I know MP3 is a codec that is fairly commonly supported, and being that MP3 isn't really a container (and therefore doesn't contain other codecs), if one works, they should all work. Someone on Super User might be able to help further, but it almost seems like there might be some corruption... Dirty disc, bad formatting, bad files, etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll take it there, see what I come up with. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an MP3-playing CD player.  It's not clear that this has anything to do with this site.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a 2006 Hyundai Sonata, and I've also had problems with certain mp3 files.  Here are the steps that usually fix the problem:

1) Make sure the encoding is 192kbps or lower
2) Make sure there are no non-ASCII characters in the tag fields, or better yet, eliminate the tags altogether.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do all the MP3s play on your computer as well? Could it be an encoding problem going from the previous format to MP3s?

Comment: They do play on my computer, just not my car. One other interesting thing is that when I select some songs in my car, they take anywhere from 5 to 15 seconds to start, then play normally. The time counter just sits at zero for that time and then (seemingly randomly) the song starts. Strange.

Comment: Man... The only thing I can think of, is that the laser for the CD player does not like the CD-R you used. Have you tried maybe getting some music specific or other kinds of CD-Rs? I really cannot fathom what else it could be.